# "Das Pferd kaut auf seinem Gebiss"

Tags: meaning

> Die Pferde kauten ungeduldig auf ihrem Gebiss.

Was bedeutet es, wenn ein Pferd auf seinem Gebiss kaut?

Comment: Solange man nicht annimmt, dass der Mensch auf dem Gebiss des Pferdes rumkaut, wird man den Ausdruck verwenden oder nicht verwenden - aber nicht im übertragenen Sinne, sondern genau so, wie beim Pferd auch. Oder  was stellst Du Dir als übertragenen Sinn vor?

Comment: English: "chomping at the bit"

Comment: @Robert It's "champing at the bit".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Gebiss* meint im Allgemeinen die Gesamtheit der Zähne (von Menschen oder Tieren, natürliche oder künstliche, also auch eine Zahnprothese - Was bei Pferden eher weniger vorkommen dürfte)

Das *Gebiss* ist allerdings auch eine Bezeichnung für einen Bestandteil des Pferdehalfters, nämlich das Metallteil, das dem Pferd zwischen die Zähne geschoben wird, die ***Trense***. Das dürfte am ehesten das sein, auf was die erwähnten Pferde kauten, Pferde, denen langweilig ist oder die ungeduldig sind, tun das manchmal.

[image]

*Picture Wikipedia*

Mit dieser Erklärung dürfte klar sein, dass der Satz (es ist **kein** stehender Ausdruck) nicht auf Menschen anwendbar ist - Die tragen normalerweise keine Trense (höchstens Hannibal Lecter)

Möglicherweise suchst du nach dem Ausdruck "mit den Zähnen knirschen", das man bildlich bei Enttäuschung oder Wut auch auf Menschen anwenden kann.